# How to use open source library in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, log4j

I would like to use [log4j.net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net) in my windows forms project. However I have never used any library or dll in .NET. How to do it? I look at the site, but I can't find it.

I'm using visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project, you need [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to the library, usually by selecting the DLL from the references dialog.

A package manager, [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/), has been created as an add on to Visual Studio 2010, which lets you select libraries - it will download and set them up for you.

Whichever way you do this, you will now be able to use the library - in a code file, use the `using` directive to import the namespace, then you can use the classes and other public members of the library in your code (though you could use the fully qualified name every time, if you wish to).

This has nothing to do with a library being open source or not, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Add the log4net assembly to your project:

1. Browse to the log4net [downloads](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html) page and download the latest log4net archive
   (right now the latest version is [1.2.10](http://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/log4net/1.2.10/incubating-log4net-1.2.10.zip)).
2. Extract that archive and place the files somewhere to your project
   (for example in a folder like `yourproject/lib/log4net`).
3. In Visual Studio right click in your project on the **References** folder and click on **Add Reference...**.
4. Browse to the folder where your assemblies are (see point 3) and choose the `log4net.dll` assembly.

Here are some nice basic tutorial for the first steps using Log4Net:

- [Log4Net Tutorial pt 1: Getting Started](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-1-Getting-Started.aspx)
- [Using Log4Net in 4 Simple Steps](http://bigjimindc.blogspot.com/2007/08/using-log4net-in-4-simple-steps.html)
- [Log error or exception using Log4Net](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/249-log-error-exception-using-log4net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily get now using NuGet package manager in visual studio 2010

Write this command in Package manager console.

```
Install-Package log4net
```

See this [link](http://www.nuget.org/Packages/Packages/Details/log4net-1-2-10)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific problems?

Check link below and maybe ask a question if you are stuck on something:

http://sadi02.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/log4net-tutorial-in-c-net-how-can-i-show-log-in-a-file/